# How to scale the sinusoid on the range $[0, 4\pi]$ to the sinusoid on the range $[1/10, 2/10]$?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

How to scale the sinusoid on the range $[0, 4pi]$ to the sinusoid on the range $[\frac{1}{10}, \frac{2}{10}]$?

I've had a couple of approaches, but I don't know how to do it. I tried use translation and it's simple, but difficult to me is linear scale

I'd like to use a python to plot:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi)

y = np.sin(x)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Edit:
My bug:

```
import numpy as np
x = (np.linspace(0,4*np.pi))

y = np.sin(x)* (1/(40*np.pi)) + 1/10
print(y)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you're trying to squeeze two wave forms into a length of $\frac{1}{10}$ which means that the period of your function should be $T = \frac{1}{20}$.  Given the formula

$$
\omega \;\; =\;\; \frac{2\pi}{T} \;\; =\;\; 40\pi
$$

and the fact that you want to shift it to the right $\frac{1}{10}$ then your function is

$$
f(x) \;\; =\;\; \sin\left [40\pi \left ( x - \frac{1}{10} \right )\right ].
$$

Comment: Where x belongs to? $x \in [0,4pi]$?

Comment: It's wrong, for example if $x=1/10$ then $f(x) \neq 0$

Comment: @Blabla Edited.  I needed a pair of parentheses.